# PowerBI Embedded - Hide specific filters

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

My report of PowerBI have three types of filters

1. hidden filters
2. visible filters
3. filters coming from drill-through

From embedded I have the option to hide the filter panel if all the filters present are not visible and show the panel if at least one filter is visible
i look at the following property for this

```
filter.displaySettings.isHiddenInViewMode
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters

But i can't manage if the filter is coming from a drillthrough or not
Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to know if the filter is applied from a hidden or visible filter or from drill through

Though you can use getFilter method (in Report, Page or Visual) to fetch details like filter type, table, column etc.

The output look something like:
[image]

**Reference:**

[Use filters when embedding a report in Power BI embedded analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters#get-filters)